# Content Porter 2013 SP1 Import Oracle DB Error

Tags: content-porter-2013, oracle

I am attempting to export from a Dev instance to a clean Prod instance of 2013 SP1 with Content Porter SP1. I have not set up my blueprint in the ProdTCM (except for empty parent setup when successfully verified the installation/configuration). Both environments are matching per hardware/software. Using Oracle 11.0.2.4.

There is very little content, so I have tried to export/import the entire site with a size of 3.91 MB. I have also just exported/imported 1 publication at a time, beginning with Administration, 000 Empty Parent and 010 Schema Master. All have consistent error: 
`Tridion.ContentManager.InvalidLinkException: Link to Schema has invalid value. ---> Tridion.ContentManager.DatabaseException: A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure "EDA_ITEMS.READ_ITEM".`

Does anyone have a guess on how I could find more detail into exactly what error this is pertaining too in the stacktrace below?

```
[Error] Tridion.ContentManager.InvalidLinkException: Link to Schema has invalid value. ---> Tridion.ContentManager.DatabaseException: A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure "EDA_ITEMS.READ_ITEM". ---> Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kdsgrp1], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck, Int32 isRecoverable)
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src)
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetString(Int32 i)
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Oracle.OracleDatabaseUtilities.ConvertToFieldDictionary(IDataRecord dataRecord)
at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Oracle.OracleDatabaseUtilities.Execute(StoredProcedureInvocation storedProcedureInvocation)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Tridion.ContentManager.Utilities.ThrowInvalidLinkException(Link link, KernelException innerException)
at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.AssertValidLink(Link link)
at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.AssertValidLinks(IEnumerable`1 links)
at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.AssertValidLinks()
at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObject.SynchronizeWithSchema(SynchronizeFlags flags)
at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.ImportAction.SynchronizeContentWithSchema(IdentifiableObject item)
at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.ImportAction.<>c__DisplayClassa.<SaveItem>b__8(Boolean isRetry)
at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Process.<>c__DisplayClass2.<InvokeInErrorHandler>b__1(Boolean isRetry)
at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.AbortErrorHandler.Invoke[T](Func`2 function, LocalizableMessage message, Boolean retryAvailable, Boolean isCritical, UserReply additionalUserReplyOptions)
at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Process.InvokeInErrorHandler[T](Func`2 function, LocalizableMessage message, Boolean retryAvailable, Boolean isCritical)
at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.ImportAction.SaveItem(IdentifiableObject item, IdentifiableObjectData deltaObject)
at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.UpdateImportAction.Perform(IdentifiableObjectData itemData)
at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItem(WebDavUrl exportUrl, IList`1 dependentItemsChain, Dictionary`2 unresolvedDependencies, Boolean specialImport)
at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportDependentItems(WebDavUrl exportUrl, IList`1 dependentItemsChain, Dictionary`2 unresolvedDependencies, Boolean partialImport)
at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItem(WebDavUrl exportUrl, IList`1 dependentItemsChain, Dictionary`2 unresolvedDependencies, Boolean specialImport)
at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportDependentItems(WebDavUrl exportUrl, IList`1 dependentItemsChain, Dictionary`2 unresolvedDependencies, Boolean partialImport)
at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItem(WebDavUrl exportUrl, IList`1 dependentItemsChain, Dictionary`2 unresolvedDependencies, Boolean specialImport)
at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportDependentItems(WebDavUrl exportUrl, IList`1 dependentItemsChain, Dictionary`2 unresolvedDependencies, Boolean partialImport)
at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItem(WebDavUrl exportUrl, IList`1 dependentItemsChain, Dictionary`2 unresolvedDependencies, Boolean specialImport)
at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportDependentItems(WebDavUrl exportUrl, IList`1 dependentItemsChain, Dictionary`2 unresolvedDependencies, Boolean partialImport)
at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItem(WebDavUrl exportUrl, IList`1 dependentItemsChain, Dictionary`2 unresolvedDependencies, Boolean specialImport)
at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItem(WebDavUrl exportUrl, IList`1 dependentItemsChain, Dictionary`2 unresolvedDependencies, Boolean specialImport)
at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItems(IList`1 items, Boolean specialGroupImport)
at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.Import(String packageName)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears from the following error message (at the end of your first line of logging):

> Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kdsgrp1], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

... that this **may** be an [Oracle issue](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-00600) (possibly a corrupt database file):
https://community.oracle.com/message/10178607#10178607, rather than a Tridion one.

I've done a quick search of the usual places (SDL Tridion World, online documentation, etc.) but I cannot see anything similar to your issue.

I would suggest that, unless someone else here knows of a fix, that you log this with Tridion Support.

Alternatively, you could try recreating the Tridion Content Manager database again (in PROD) and starting again.

Incidentally, as this is a clean PROD environment, have you considered [taking a backup of the database in DEV and then restoring this in PROD](http://www.oivetic.com/blog/2014/How_to_Restore_Tridion_Databases.html) (the steps will be slightly different for Prod), rather than Content Porting? There are a number of items that Content Porter does not move between environments (Users, Groups, etc.), so it would avoid you having to move these manually. This would take all of the items that you have in DEV across to PROD, some of which will probably need to be deleted, so this may not be an option!

Comment: Oracle FAQ (http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-00600) suggests to contact Oracle support, as it definitely sounds like something wrong on the database.

Comment: @Johnathan Williams - Yes. I have considered doing a DB dump into Prod and would definitely need to clean up any used items as you mentioned above. Appreciate the link for the steps on the how-to

Comment: @Bart Koopman - I am following up with Oracle support now.

Answer (score 1):

After working with DBA to have the Tridion CM schema/db on an **Active/Passive** scenario within a cluster per [SDL Model](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/concept_282808B193ED4FB39D6124A28B057718). I was able to successfully promote content via `Content Porter`

I am not sure if this is related, but before the switch to A/P we also noticed that the Archive log generation and SMON locking issue below were resolved per @JonathanWilliams recommendation to do a data dump - after we copied the data from DEV into our Stage.

As per this scenario, shows that some of the objects got corrupted in `TCMDBUSER`, So SMON oracle process was trying to recover, which causes the SMON lock and more archive log generation.

[image]

Comment: I guess there's one "Active/Passive" in your text that should be "Active/Active" instead?

Comment: Content Porter only uses public APIs, so it doesn't really have any requirements of its own. It could be that some of the operations started by Content Porter triggers this error, but Active/Passive configuration for RAC is a CM requirement, not Content Porter.